# Why is my XAML ToggleButton invisible to the code-behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, appbar

I have a ToggleButton in MainPage.xaml:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ColorToggle" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Change Toolbar Color">
```

...yet when I try to access it from MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void SaveAppBarColorSelected(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PhotraxUtils.SetLocalSetting(PhotraxConsts.APPBARBUTTON_COLOR, ColorToggle.Background.ToString());
}
```

...I get, "*The name 'ColorToggle' does not exist in the current context*"

Why is that?

Comment: Yes - ToggleButton is in MainPage.xaml, and the method is in MapnPage.xaml.cs. It is declared within a ControlTemplate in the xaml.

Comment: Set its DataContext to your View to reach outside of the ControlTemplate it sits in via relativesource or directly. ;)

Comment: "MainPage", not "MapnPage" (although that typo does sort of make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only controls from the root context are available in code-behind. If you place your named control inside a template, it won't be available. You can traverse the controls tree using `VisualTreeHelper` and other methods in this case.

Or better yet, just use MVVM.